Reducing the size of an Arduino program: Compilation error: text section exceeds available space in board
I need to reduce the size of my esp32 program have no clue how
#include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <pgmspace.h>
#include "BluetoothSerial.h" // Include BluetoothSerial header
#pragma GCC optimize ("Os")

const char deviceName[] PROGMEM = "ESPMaster";
const unsigned long bluetoothTimeout = 5000; // 5 seconds
unsigned long lastActivityTime = 0;

BluetoothSerial SerialBT; // Declare SerialBT instance

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

    if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
        Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
        return;
    }

    SerialBT.begin(deviceName); // Initialize SerialBT with deviceName
    Serial.println(F("The device with name \"ESPMaster\" is started.\nNow you can pair it with Bluetooth!"));
}

void loop() {
    // Check for incoming data on Serial
    while (Serial.available()) {
        SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
        lastActivityTime = millis();
    }

    // Check for Bluetooth timeout
    if (millis() - lastActivityTime >= bluetoothTimeout) {
        lastActivityTime = millis();
        // Read acceleration data and send via Bluetooth
        // (Assuming acceleration data is read from specific memory addresses as in previous examples)
        float accelerationX = *((float*)0x3FF00000);
        float accelerationY = *((float*)0x3FF00004);
        float accelerationZ = *((float*)0x3FF00008);

        char buffer[24]; // Reduced buffer size
        snprintf_P(buffer, sizeof(buffer), PSTR("X: %.2f, Y: %.2f, Z: %.2f m/s^2\n"), accelerationX, accelerationY, accelerationZ);

        SerialBT.print(buffer);
    }
}

Sketch uses 1480309 bytes (112%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 57044 bytes (17%) of dynamic memory, leaving 270636 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
Sketch too big; see https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360013825179 for tips on reducing it.
text section exceeds available space in board
I have tried using some registers and removing unnecessary functions.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you checked the map file to see which part of your libraries takes up the most space and is worth optimising?

If you are using Arduino IDE, change the settings on Tools -> Partition Scheme to allocate more for your flash memory.

both god suggestions, i ended up doing a MQTT solution instead as I was very pressed for time and had experience with MQTT
